# How to design ink! storage to prevent OutOfGas?

Tags: ink

I'm trying to write a simple contract but run OutOfGas very quickly. My main storage looks like this:

```rust
    type Id = u32;

    #[ink(storage)]
    pub struct Example {
        elements: Mapping<Id, Element>,
        ids: Lazy<Vec<Id>>,
    }

    #[derive(scale::Encode, scale::Decode)]
    #[cfg_attr(
        feature = "std",
        derive(scale_info::TypeInfo, ink::storage::traits::StorageLayout)
    )]
    pub struct Element {
        id: Id,
        name: String,
        owner: AccountId,
        max_speed: i32,
        max_inventory_size: u32,
        max_cargo_size: u32,
        max_energy: u32,
        max_health: u32,
        recharge_rate: u32,
    }
```

When I now try to create one of those elements via a message I'm running out of gas no matter how much I supply. What can be the reason for this? Is the Element struct perhaps too large for a single Cell, so it's super inefficient? What else could be the reason?

Thanks in advance, any input would be appreciated!

Comment: difficult to identify the exact cause if you have enough balance. Can you please share the code link so that I can compile and deploy in my system if possible

Comment: yeah weight v2 hasn't merged there so you may face bug there in the mean time you can use https://polkadotjs-apps.web.app/#/contracts

Comment: https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/pull/8538 still not merged so you faced bug

Comment: Contracts UI is also available which is compatible with weight V2
https://contracts-ui.substrate.io/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered a similar issue when upgrading to the latest version of substrate and ink smart contracts. Let me tell you what worked for me.

Initially, when deploying a smart contract I would have a gasLimit as a number

```
  const code = new CodePromise(api, abi, wasm);
  const gasLimit = 300000000000n;
  code.tx
    .new(
      { gasLimit, salt: randomAsHex() },
      initialSupply,
      price,
      owner,
      date,
      redeemableAddress,
      purchaseTrackerAddress
    )
```

But this was giving me the outOfGas error, I would increase this limit until it would exhaust the block limit so that was no good. I did see that I could deploy the contract on the contracts-ui (https://contracts-ui.substrate.io/).  Which was great! They declare the gasLimit like this:

```
    const code = new CodePromise(api, abi, wasm);
  const gasLimit = api.registry.createType("WeightV2", {
    refTime: 300000000000n,
    proofSize: 262144,
  });

  code.tx
    .new(
      { gasLimit, salt: randomAsHex() },
      initialSupply,
      price,
      owner,
      date,
      redeemableAddress,
      purchaseTrackerAddress
    )
```

I would recommend uploading your contract to the contract UI and it will tell you what refTime and proofSize values you should use.

Hope this solves your problem!

Comment: My initial problem from the top post was indeed about the weights v2 not being merged, but I found a link back here to my own question while searching for a different OutOfGas problem and your solution works! Thank you :)

Comment: Super happy it worked!

Comment: Brillant thing, It solved a big problem of instantiation using json RPC