# How to fix Contract.outOfGas error

Tags: polkadot-js, ink, contracts

I'm trying to call a message on my ink! v3 smart contract using the polkadot-js `ContractPromise` but I'm getting the error:

```
system.ExtrinsicFailed::ExtrinsicFailed:: contracts.OutOfGas
```

This is how I'm making the call:

```
  const eventList: EventList[] = [];
  const pr = new Promise((res, rej) => {
    // Dry run the call
    contract.query
      .initiateVerficationFlow(address, {})
      .then((value) => {
        // create weightV2 type by calling registry.createType, similar to https://github.com/paritytech/contracts-ui/blob/master/src/helpers/callOptions.ts#L42
        const gasLimit = getGasLimit(
          value.gasRequired.refTime.toBn(),
          value.gasRequired.proofSize.toBn(),
          contract.registry
        );

        // Make the call, and listen to events
        contract.tx
          .initiateVerficationFlow({
            storageDepositLimit: value.storageDeposit.asCharge,
            gasLimit: gasLimit,
            value: 100n,
          })
          .signAndSend(
            address,
            signer,
            handleEvents(contract.api as ApiPromise, [0, eventList], res, rej)
          );
      })
      .catch(rej);
  });

  const response = await pr;
  console.log(response);
```

I noticed that this call resolves successfully with the polkadot-js web app from ink-waterfall: https://polkadotjs-apps.web.app/ , and the contracts-ui https://contracts-ui.substrate.io/contract .

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: [her you can find your answer](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7358/how-to-design-ink-storage-to-prevent-outofgas). It's basically [WeightsV2 support for contracts pallet hasn't merged ](https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/pull/8538) on polkadotjs.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, WeightsV2 is the issue. You can do it the "low level" way with PolkadotJS that involves encoding / decoding the data, or if you are using React you can use [useink beta](https://www.npmjs.com/package/useink) `useContractTx` hook.

1. [Here is what it does under the hood](https://github.com/paritytech/useink/blob/fa37e428649e6c2a5be7e881b4737e346e978b05/core/hooks/useContractTx.ts#L42) if you are not using React.
2. With React:

```
const contract = useContract(...yourArgs)
const tx = useContactTx(contract, 'myMessageName');
const txArgs = ['Squink', 1000];

return (
  <div>
    <button onClick(() => tx.send(txArgs)>Submit</button
    Status: {tx.status}
  </div>
)
```

`useink` is beta now and has come big changes coming up, but it will do all of the nasty decoding work and handle WeightsV2 under the hood for you.

There are more hooks in there you may find useful. E.g. `useContractCall`, which will read from the contract on each new block.

Answer (score 1):

The `polkadot-js` UI unfortunately doesn't support Weights V2 yet.

You are better off using https://contracts-ui.substrate.io/ for now.